# Prove $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n^2}$ using the fraction criteria

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I found a lot of ways to prove that  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n^2}$ converges.

I wondered if you could also prove it using the the [fraction criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) ($\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} |\frac {a_n+1} {a_n}|<1)$ and that $\frac 1 {n^2} < \frac 1  {(n-1)\cdot n}$

Which results in: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac {a_n+1} {a_n} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac {n-1} {n} = 1  $

However my textbook says it you could still show that it converges with $=1$ but I do not understand what it does. Can someone of you help me out?

Comment: You are asking if one can apply a criterion requiring that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} |\frac {a_n+1} {a_n}|<1$ to a series such that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} |\frac {a_n+1} {a_n}|=1$? The answer is clearly "no", if only for reasons of *pure logic*, don't you think?

Comment: Did you want to write $a_n+1$ or $a_{n+1}$ in the numerator? You can typeset the latter as `a_{n+1}`.

Comment: Perhaps it would be also good if you were more specific about what you mean by *my textbook*. At least name of the book (and perhaps edition), chapter and page number where the claim you mention can be find. And you might also add a link (if it is online or in Google Books). Or retype relevant passage if it is not too long (perhaps even screenshot would be better than nothing).

Comment: I think what your textbook means is that if you get 1, you can still show it converges by other means; I don't think it's meant that you can still use the ratio test in that case.

Comment: You can't drive a screw to the wall with a hammer (at least not well). You need another tool.

Answer (score 4):

Not gonna work.  You *can* show it converges in various ways, but this isn't one of them; once you get an indeterminate answer from the ratio test, it's time to move on to a different test.  (The integral test is the easiest one here, I think, but from the timbre of your questions, I don't think you're there yet...)

So let's do it this way.

$$\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n^2+n} \therefore$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{n^2+n} = 1 - \frac{1}{m+1} \therefore\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2+n} = 1$$

So you use the limit comparison test:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n^2+n}} = 1$$

Therefore they both converge or both diverge; therefore they both converge.

Answer (score 1):

Note that when $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n} = 1$ you can't conclude that the series diverges or converges.

For example:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n} = 1$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n^2}$ converges and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n} = 1$